# Discord js direct message await not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, discord.js

So my discord bot asks a user in DM for an API secret. I want to await the user's response so that I can do further things with my key.

From `client.on('messageCreate')` after a user requests to add key I call this function

```js
async function takeApiSecret(msg) {

    const botMsg = await msg.author.send("Please provide your api secret");
    const filter = collected => collected.author.id === msg.author.id;

    const collected = await botMsg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
      max: 1,
      time: 50000,
  }).catch(() => {
    msg.author.send('Timeout');
  });
```

However I am not able to await the user's response and collect it. Instead when I reply I get another message on my `client.on('messageCreate')`. Any leads what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: What does the message say instead?

Comment: @MrMythical nothing ... I dont get any error at all.

Comment: What version of discord.js are you on?

Comment: @MrMythical 13.10 and Node 16.8.0

Comment: Well you should know that awaitMessages filters are now in the first argument as a property of the object, so it should look like this:
`awaitMessages({filter, max: 1, time: 50000})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In discord.js v13.x, the parameters of `awaitMessages()` changed a little bit. There are no longer separate parameters for `filter` and `options`; `filter` is now contained within options. This should fix your problem:

```js
const filter = collected => collected.author.id === msg.author.id;

const collected = await botMsg.channel.awaitMessages({
    filter,
    max: 1,
    time: 50000,
}).catch(() => {
    msg.author.send('Timeout');
});
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages). For some reason, the options do not appear to be fully documented, but you can view the example on that page to see the new format.

---

Additionally, if this code is called whenever a message is sent via DM, you may need to prevent collected messages from triggering the rest of your `messageCreate` event listener code. Here's one way you could do that:

Outside `messageCreate` handler:

```js
const respondingUsers = new Set();
```

Right before `awaitMessages()`

```js
respondingUsers.add(msg.author.id);
```

Inside your `.then()` and `.catch()` on your `awaitMessages()`:

```js
respondingUsers.delete(msg.author.id);
```

Near the top of your `messageCreate` handler, right after your other checks (e.g. checking if the message is a DM):

```js
if (respondingUsers.has(msg.author.id)) return;
```

---

If we put all of this together, it may look something like this (obviously, modify this to work with your code):

```js
const respondingUsers = new Set();

client.on('messageCreate', msg => {

    if (msg.channel.type != "DM") return;
    if (respondingUsers.has(msg.author.id)) return;

    respondingUsers.add(msg.author.id);
    
    const filter = collected => collected.author.id === msg.author.id;

    const collected = botMsg.channel.awaitMessages({
        filter,
        max: 1,
        time: 50000,
    })
    .then(messages => {
        msg.author.send("Received messages");
        respondingUsers.delete(msg.author.id);
    })
    .catch(() => {
        msg.author.send('Timeout');
        respondingUsers.delete(msg.author.id);
    });

})
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Really helped out. We don't need await though if we are using .then like you mention in your code though

Comment: True, I didn't see the `await` there lol. Thanks for pointing that out. I've removed it from the answer. You can adapt this to work with `async/await` if you want though (honestly, it's much cleaner that way as opposed to using `.then`).